# Xcode 9 code completion not working for @interface @implemetation

Tags: xcode

When I input `@interface` or `@implemetation`, there is no code completion. Others' code completion work fine. Is that function removed or it is a bug?

Comment: its absolutely expected behavior ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found the answer is that **input `interface` or `implemetation` without `@`**, search the list of auto completion and select "Objective-C Class Interface/Implemetation" and that is it.

If you don't see that one in the list, just page down until you find it that start with a `{}` icon. If you've used it once, it'll be at the first place in the auto completion list next time.